# Core i7 vs Xeon in a different scenario

Tags: hyper-v, intel-core-i7, android-studio, xeon, simulation

I googled to know the difference between i7 and Xeon processors mostly both processors are compared with gaming perspective.

I want to run Hyper-V and Android Stuido for simulations, please help me what are the most important things i should keep in mind.

In such scenario what is the importance of # of Cores, # of threads and Cache size (like 6mb Cache etc.) ?

is it better to install ram in smaller modules like instead of 16gbx2 should I install 8gbx4 modules?

And also in this scenario is it helpful to use dual processor or its better to use one but newer?

Comment: Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly.

Comment: thanks i understand, i updated my question to make it more relevant to technical requirements towards a scenario where user wants to understand thing relevant to system performance regarding Hyper-V and using simulators

Comment: What matters is not numbers on the spec sheet, but actual performance of particular CPU in particular task. There's much more to CPU's performance than just specs.

Comment: how do we know CPU's performance without having it? there must be some indicators, parameters to understand expected performance in scenarios like gaming, rendering, virtualization etc.

Comment: This question is way too broad, but to throw you a small bone… In broad strokes, i-series are consumer chips, meant to run one at a time, 1 mobo, 1 CPU. Xeons will rack up, as many as the mobo will take [I think max 8, I only have 2, so idk for certain]. if you want to do a *very* lot of tasks, you need a lot of Xeons. Older Xeons were also fixed clock, so they were always running at full speed. Newer ones do have a flexi-clock. RAM doesn't care, so long as it can dual or triple channel, as appropriate. 96GB as 6x16, triple, is faster than 128GB as 8x16, dual.

Comment: I thought I narrow down requirements to a specific use like Hyper V and running some simulator, may be I'm not good on these things, please help me to further narrow down requirements if needed.